# What's the differences between plugin, service and module in C9

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, c9.io

I know files and modules are in one-to-one correspondence in C9, and a package is one or more modules grouped (or packaged) together.

However, what's the relations between plugin, service and module in C9?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what context you're referring to each term. Files and modules are language specific. In the context of Cloud9, the following definitions apply:

- **Package** - a combination of plugins
- **Plugin** - a plugin to the UI of Cloud9
- **Service** - the entire Cloud9 platform

A module isn't really a thing in Cloud9. If someone uses that term, it's probably referring to a plugin.